# VLCKit on iOS has no fps when playing streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, vlc, frame-rate

When using mobileVLCKit.framework to play a live view streaming via RTSP protocol, I can't get fps info even if the displaying view is correctly shown.

Here is my code

```
NSLog(@"%.1f FPS", self.player.framesPerSecond);
```

The result is always "0.0 FPS", and is not reasonable.

I used framesPerSecond since fps is deprecated, as said in http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MobileVLCKit/2.2.1/Classes/VLCMediaPlayer.html

Tracing to VLC source and I found

```
- (float)framesPerSecond
{
    return libvlc_media_player_get_fps(_playerInstance);  
}
```

it looks correct, but I still don't know why the result is wrong.

Could someone give me suggestion or some work around method to get fps info?

Any reply would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might missed from the doc, see " this property is deprecated. use (float)fps instead." , (You can still use fps which returns a float value_

Comment: I tried. self.player.fps returned the same result.

Comment: Today, I tried several different rtsp streaming source and you guess what? Some source shows "10.0 FPS"....   That is strange, and I guess the value was rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't enable statistics on iOS / within MobileVLCKit by default, so any statistic value will always be 0. To enable it, you need to compile the framework yourself.

To enable stats, remove `@"--no-stats"` from VLCLibrary.m. Further, after the build script downloaded `MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc`, stop its execution, edit `MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios/build.sh`, remove the line `stats` from the blacklist, and restart the script.

Comment: Grateful for your reply, I'll try to build it, and give you the result! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have a question. If the two settings are not enough. I mean that I tried remove @"--no-stats" from VLCLibrary.m and remove stats from the blacklist. The fps function seems not enabled. I guess if there is some missing setting that blocks the fps?

Comment: @feepk i am unable to play the Audio url with MobileVLCKit but i am able to play the video urls. Can you please suggest me how to achieve this